# What are the origins of the various forms of Gematria?

Tags: reference

I just read through [gematrix.org's](https://www.gematrix.org/gematria.php) gematria system(s), which it takes from various places. It includes:

- Jewish Gematria (system 1)
- (Old) English Gematria (system 2)
- Straightforward Latin Gematria (system 3)
- Aik Bekar Latin Gematria (system 4)
- E.Q. Latin Gematria (system 5)
- Latin Qabalah Simplex Gematria (system 6)

The old english one seems to be where 666 comes from, as in "Mark of Beast". That uses strange seemingly random values for each English/Latin letter, whereas the "straightforward" one uses 1, 2, 3, etc. for the alphabet letters up to 26, like you would expect. The Aik Bekar one makes sense if you only use digits 1-9 and start over as you go through the alphabet. The others don't make sense where they came from. The Jewish one doesn't make sense either, it uses for example `J=600`, while the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gematria#English_Gematria) says `J=10`.

My question is, what are the sources for these systems of Gematria? I would like to know how the other seemingly random values (beyond the 2 that make sense) were derived.

If you read through gematrix's post, it says how the ancient societies used gematria heavily, so assuming that, it has been around long before the medieval times. But these systems seem relatively recent, so I am confused where this information is coming from.

Note, outside of this site, there are a few other numerology systems like in [arabic](https://charactercalculator.com/abjad-calculator/).

Comment: Can you say where your research fell down, and what up to that point had been the useful results? The details in the Question look interesting, but don't seem helpful…